# WPF Datagrid and Entity Framework

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I'm new to WPF.

Can anyone give me any good tutorial how binding datagrid to entity framework?
I've generated the objects model from database with entity framework: i want show on the datagrid the content of some table.
How can i add/delete/modify datagrid cell/row and so update the database?

Thanks

Comment: ;) Ask someone who already did it to do it for you. Not meanin this sarcastic - this IS The fastest way and you don't even have to waste time yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Here are very basic examples ,

[Data binding with WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574514.aspx)

[Data binding with entity framework and wpf](http://learnentityframework.com/LearnEntityFramework/tutorials/wpf-databinding-with-entity-framework/)